# How to open an existing Flutter Project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I might sound noob here but I can't see a clear way of opening existing Flutter Project in Android Studio `3.1.2`.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067999/flutter-how-to-import-existing-flutter-project-as-a-gradle-project) but it didn't work. So I want to know if there is a standard IDE way of doing this? I also can't find any docs clearly mentioning it. Do I need to install a 3rd party plugin?

After opening it as an Existing Android Studio Project, I get the following error:

[image: error]

The error is solved by running `Get Dependencies`. Is it a normal behavior?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Install Flutter plugin for Android studio: https://flutter.io/get-started/editor/
2. Open Android Studio
3. Open existing Android Studio project by using one of below methods:

---

**EASIEST WAY: Drag your project folder and drop to Android Studio.**

---

Other ways:

[image: Android Studio 1]

[image: Android Studio 2]

[image: Android Studio 3]

Comment: I have edited my question. Just want to ask whether `Get Dependencies` error message is a normal behavior?

Comment: Can you click on Get Dependencies on top right? And then run the app? If you can run the app, all is OK I guess

Comment: Yes it is solved after that. Though I have to do this when opening any existing project.

Comment: Yes, and you have to Get Dependencies again any time that you subsequently change pubspec.yaml (i.e. when you add additional dependencies).

Comment: Yes, like when you add dependencies to your build.gradle file in Android project :)

Comment: For me, Android Studio opens an existing, never before opened project in the 'Android' view in the project pane. For a Flutter project that doesn't make sense (by default), so I have to switch to the regular 'Project' view.

Comment: Furthermore, when opening a Dart file, the IDE might prompt you to enable Dart for the project. After that make sure to open the pubspec and upgrade/get dependencies before building.

Answer (score 23):

What works for me was to open existing Android Studio project like mentioned above, and then go to menu

> Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean

Then configuration window will open and ask you to locate flutter sdk. After locating the sdk, click OK and then the flutter functions will be available (Pub buttons, runs menu). After that you can proceed to get the dependencies (**pub get**).

It's basically cleaning the project folder of previous setting(s) which might conflicting with the system (android studio). But that won't happen if you get the project from source repository because all of the junk files wont be in the project folder.

Comment: Perfect! It is what I was looking for

Comment: Thank you! This is what was missing for me.

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way on **macOS** is
`open -a Android\ Studio android` when you are in the root project directory.

---

Alternatively, if you use the jetbrains toolbox, you can enable "Shell Scripts" in its settings. This will create a binary in the folder of your choice, so you have to add this folder to your `PATH`. Then, you can use `studio .` inside the Android folder, or `studio android` in the flutter project. The benefit of this, is it also works with other Jetbrains products (e.g. `charm project_dir` or `clion project_dir`. Unfortunately this method glitches out (for pycharm at least).

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Android Studio can't load Android Application module from Flutter project automatically. I also have same problem, so in my situation Gradle can't be found, because of lack of Android project.

There's **important** note from official [site](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio):

> **Important**: Do not use the New > Project from existing sources option for Flutter projects

I suggest, same is for Open option.

Answer (score 4):

Just Open your project as normal, and then in [Android Studio > Preferences > Languages&Frameworks > Flutter > Flutter SDK path] select the path where you downloaded & unpacked Flutter SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's already late, but you can open an existing Flutter project in Android Studio by following these steps (make sure you have already installed Flutter & Dart plugin and Flutter SDK):

1. Click Open from File menu in Android Studio,
2. Go to the path of the project,
3. Click Open from the dialog,
4. When the project opens in Android studio, it will show an error of packages and dependencies. So, click on Get Dependencies on the top. Android Studio will automatically add all the required dependencies and packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way of doing this in android:

Just Open your project as normal, and on the top right corner, click on **Flutter Attach** option, and voila!

See Attached screen grab!

[image]

Comment: And then click on the project window... where it says "Android"(upper left corner), and change it to "Project"... Thanks, amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can open your Flutter project in Android Studio simply when you right click on the **android folder** > **Flutter** > **Open Android module in Android Studio** but sometimes this option could be disabled, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965538/7360275) to enable..

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution** : just run "flutter pub get" in the terminal OR
click on Tools->flutter->flutter pub get.(you should have configured the flutter sdk location and plugin). [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMCHd.png)