# Flutter: Open android module in Android Studio is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to open my flutter project separately in android studio with "Open android module in Android Studio" but when I left click on my flutter project window to open it this is disabled for me while "Open iOS module in Xcode" is there. Please let me know I can I enable it and can open my flutter project for android in another module.

Comment: There is an issue created for this on flutter/flutter-intellij repo https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3873

Answer (score 56):

**>>> Only applies for Idea Intellij IDE**

Okay, I finally figured out why the option is not available (greyed out).

It should be the inconsistency problem between the old version of the flutter plugin and a new one.

You might experience this issue if you created the project with a relatively old version flutter engine, and open it with a new version flutter plugin.

**To know what happens and how to resolve it:**

The old project contains a file: 
[image: android.iml]

which is not the same as in a latest created project:
[image: $projectname_android.iml]

So you know how to fix the issue:

**Rename the iml file to (YourProjectName_android.iml)**
That would instantly make the menu highlight again!

Comment: I don have the .iml file

Comment: @shahanakareen after some searches I found that .iml is generated for Idea Intellij IDE. If you use other IDEs then you won't have it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am using Android studio and i just imported a flutter project from gitlab. Now I am not getting that option to edit android module. I can see a iml file under the root of the folder but not inside android folder

Comment: @shahanakareen The option is used to open the project from other IDEs by Android Studio. It's not the case you import it directly FROM the Android Studio. You've already done what it does. If you don't know how to edit android modules, you have to find other questions.

Comment: thanks, it works for me! I didn't have the .iml file at first, but when i File -> Open the android project the .iml file is automatically generated by android studio and then i rename the .iml file to YourProjectName_android.iml it's worked!

Comment: the iml file name depends on the project folder, if app folder name is `test_app_one` iml file name will be `test_app_one_android.iml`

Comment: " flutter create ." will create this file automatically

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, works like charm on `Flutter 2.10.4` and `Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1`

Comment: @anyone who doesn't see the .iml file in the android module, you have to create that file manually. Follow [this link](http://www.praveenboyalapalli.com/flutter-menu-option-is-disabled/) and it will definitely work

Answer (score 54):

Simply do the following:

1. Right click on `android` folder > `New` > `File`
2. Rename the new file **myproject_android.iml** (change **myproject** to your project name)
3. Paste the bellow xml code and save it
4. Right click on `android` folder > `Flutter` > `Open Android Module in Android Studio`
5. Voila

**Xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/lib" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.dart_tool" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.idea" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.pub" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Dart SDK" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Flutter Plugins" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Dart Packages" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: This solution worked for me as my project was started some time ago.

Answer (score 22):

Because you lost the **xxx_android.iml** file in android directory, it cannot be recognized as an android project.

So you only need to copy a **xxx_android.iml** file from other projects to the android directory.

Note, replace **xxx** with your project name

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to use this command in the root directory of your project, it will create some missing files and it will definitely work.

```
flutter create --platforms=android .
```

Now just right click to Android folder

[image]

Comment: This is the simplest and straightforward solution

Answer (score 6):

Go to

```
tools -> flutter -> open in exisiting android studio.
```

If it is not showing, then create a Dummy project in flutter, after that `dummyFil.iml` is generating with new Flutter Plugins.

Paste the `dummyFil.iml` file in your project.

You will see a option  as open in existing android studio option.

Answer (score 0):

My plugin is a pure package having no example app that also caused the same issue. I fixed at following:

1. Generate new plugin
   `flutter create --template=plugin --platforms=android -a java YourPluginName`
2. Copy example app into my plugin
3. Go to example/android, right click on your_plugin_example.iml, Flutter/Open for Editing on Android Studio
4. The flutter module is loaded so there will be no error.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got this issue i make a file in project-> android-> projectname_android.iml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
<component name="FacetManager">
<facet type="android" name="Android">
<configuration>
<option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
<option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_APT" value="/gen" />
<option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_AIDL" value="/gen" />
<option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
<option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/res" />
 <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/assets" />
  <option name="LIBS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/libs" />
    <option name="PROGUARD_LOGS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/proguard_logs" />
</configuration>
</facet>
</component>
 <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">

<exclude-output />
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app/src/main/kotlin" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
</content>
 <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="11" jdkType="JavaSDK" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="Flutter for Android" level="project" />
 <orderEntry type="library" name="KotlinJavaRuntime" level="project" />
</component>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

deleting `.idea` folder under `your_project/android/` worked for me.