# I want to run the Flutter gallery sample in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

https://gallery.flutter.dev/

I want to execute the sample code on the above page in android studio, but I don't know how to execute it.

https://github.com/flutter/gallery/

For the time being, I downloaded and unzipped the zip file on the above page, how can I open this project in android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to Clone the project to your android studio:
See image below:
[image: First Step]

Second, open your Android Studio and on the welcome page choose "Check out project from Version Control" and then choose "Git".
See image below:
[image: Second Step]

Next, paste the link and choose where you want to save it. And then click "Clone"
See image below:
[image: Next Step]

NOTE: If a pop-up said "Checkout from version control" appears, you can choose yes/no.

And then, remember to click on "Get Dependencies"
See image below:
[image: Get Dependencies]

NOTE: If the option doesn't appear, run `flutter pub get` in your terminal

Comment: Thank you for your response.
As a result of working according to the answer I received, the run button (Run'main.dart') of android studio is gray and cannot be pressed.
On top
'Dart SDK is not configured'
Is displayed.
What should I do?

Comment: It worked when I tried it again.
Thank you for the easy-to-understand explanation.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548629/how-to-open-an-existing-flutter-project-in-android-studio)

But sometime importing a new project may lead to unforeseen and  unwanted errors('ve faced this many times) like : this file or that file is missing . So I recommend creating a new flutter project and manually copying dart files to /lib folder , AndroidManifest and both gradle files to appropriate places etc. Also update the pubspec.yaml to add dependencies .  There are other things which you might to add or update but I like this way because it helps you to understand how a project is made , though it's upon you how you do it . Good luck.